# Php - Image processing and manipulation

Tags: php, image, gis, image-manipulation, imagefilter

I need an elegant and fast way to gather all the rgb pixel value from an image (large) images. My concern is I will not be able to hold values in memory and also the createfromjpeg() method will be slow. I would need storage to hold intermediate data. What would be my options?

Secondly, I need to apply custom filters or process these pixels. Refer me some new filter concepts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you'd better use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). While your question is very borad (and has no code samples whatsoever ;-)), this might be a good start but needs a little bit of reading. It has a `python` library as well as an (unofficial) [wrapper for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP).

Answer (score -1):

jquery code:

```
$(function() {

$('img').mousemove(function(e) {

    if(!this.canvas) {
        this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
        this.canvas.width = this.width;
        this.canvas.height = this.height;
        this.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }

    var pixelData = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

    $('#output').html('R: ' + pixelData[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixelData[1] + '<br>B: ' + pixelData[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixelData[3]);


       });

  });
```

html code:

```
         <pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! However, the question was flagged as `PHP` and you offered a jQuery/Javascript approach.